# Is it possible to index an R list using a character variable and the '$' operator?

Tags: r, list

Can someone explain why I get `NULL` in the following ?

```
> a =  list( 'key'='val')
> a$'key'
[1] "val"
> a$key
[1] "val"
> key_var = 'key'
> a$key_var
NULL
```

I know that I can do

```
> a[[key_val]]
[1] "val"
```

but I think double brackets can get messy (especially when working with nested lists, etc).

Comment: For passing object names to subset you should use `[` and not `$`.  Please check `?'$'`

Comment: Look at this case: `key_var = 'key'; a =  list( key='val', key_var="hello"); a$key_var`. What should be returned? That's just how the `$` operator works. You can't use it with variables. The `[[` syntax is perfect for this operation. I'm sorry you think they are messy.